# How can I get a Hindi transliteration keyboard in Fedora Linux? (like there's Google Indic for Android)

Tags: linux, fedora, virtualbox, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am new to using **Fedora Linux**. While setting it up through my Virtual box Machine on Win10 it asked for input keyboards. I usually work in English (in/en) keyboards, but sometimes I had to do some typing work in Hindi.

It showed 3 categories for Hindi keyboards: *Bolnagri, KaGaPa & Wx*. However on checking them up on internet, I found all of them were actually **Phonetic Keyboards** *(Hindi script, Hindi typing)*.

Whilst I am more comfortable to work on **Transliteration Keyboards** *(Roman script, Hindi typing)*, just like we have Google Indic keyboards in Android [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IBpJ.jpg)